# pyqgis : Load WMS layer and make him invisible (qgis 3.4.3 )

Tags: python, pyqgis, wms, qgis-3

I am loading WMS layer in Python console with simple code. Then I try to make the layer invisible in TOC, but not success. I run the code in QGIS 3.4.3 in Python console in Windows 10.

```
from qgis.core import QgsLayerTreeLayer,QgsProject 

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

url_cur= "url='https://ags.iplan.gov.il/arcgis/rest/services/PlanningPublic/Xplan_2039/MapServer' layer='0'"

layer = iface.addRasterLayer( url_cur, 'a1', "arcgismapserver")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer,False)

treeLay0 = QgsLayerTreeLayer (layer)

treeLay0.setItemVisibilityChecked (Qt.Unchecked )
```

Comment: Matthias, Thank you very much. It's works. Here is the right code::

Comment: from qgis.core import QgsLayerTreeLayer, QgsProject 
url_cur = "url='https://ags.iplan.gov.il/arcgis/rest/services/PlanningPublic/Xplan_2039/MapServer' layer='0'"
layer = iface.addRasterLayer( url_cur, 'a1', "arcgismapserver")
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)